# Change the text of a span element on click on an anchor element

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

```
<div class="input-group-btn search-panel" id="change-text">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <span id="search_concept change-text-span">Select Location</span>
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu" role="menu">
        <li>
            <a href="#Link" id="change-text-a">Odisha</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

In the above code, I need to change the text of the `span` element on click of the  `a` element. How can I do this?

Please Help.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? If so, please edit your question to include that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#change-text-a").click(function() {
   $(".caret").text("SEt content here");
});
```